# Show/Hide iframe until selected

Tags: html, css, iframe

Currently, the frame is on top of each other and some showed even if I did not choose it.

```
<div>
<div>
<iframe src="index2.php" width="100%" height="100%" name="index2"></iframe>
</div>
<div>
<iframe src="profile.php" width="100%" height="100%" name="profile"></iframe>
</div>
</div>

<label>Sample choices</label>
<div>
<a href="index2.php" target="index2">Home</a>
<a href="profile.php" target="profile">profile</a>
</div>
```

nothing will display first then if I select one the other is hide till I select it. the display should be on the same spot/place. Sorry newbies here.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested so excuse any typos but perhaps the following might be of help

```
<style>
    #container > div{display:none}
</style>

<div id='container'>
    <div>
        <iframe src="index2.php" width="100%" height="100%" name="index2"> </iframe>
    </div>
    <div>
        <iframe src="profile.php" width="100%" height="100%" name="profile"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>

<label>Sample choices</label>
<div>
    <a href="index2.php" target="index2">Home</a>
    <a href="profile.php" target="profile">profile</a>
</div>

<script>
    document.querySelectorAll( 'a[target]' ).forEach( a=>{
        a.addEventListener('click',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            document.getElementById('container').querySelector( '[name="'+this.getAttribute('target')+'"]').parentNode.style.display='block';
        });
    })
</script>
```

---

A simple demo to illustrate the showing of the iframe. If this is not as intended please clarify the question

```
/*ifsrc1.php*/

<?php

    echo " I am the iFrame source for index2";

?>


/* ifsrc2.php */
<?php

    echo " I am the iFrame source for profile";

?>
```

The main page with the hidden iframes

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
        <style>
            #container > div{ display:none; width: 80%;height:10rem;border:1px solid red; margin:1rem auto;padding:0 }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='container'>
            <div>
                <iframe src="ifsrc1.php" width="100%" height="100%" name="index2"> </iframe>
            </div>
            <div>
                <iframe src="ifsrc2.php" width="100%" height="100%" name="profile"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>



        <label>Sample choices</label>
        <div>
            <a href='#' target="index2">Home</a>
            <a href='#' target="profile">profile</a>
        </div>

        <script>
            document.querySelectorAll( 'a[target]' ).forEach( a=>{


                a.addEventListener('click',function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();

                    /* hide all */
                    document.querySelectorAll('#container > div').forEach( div=>{
                        div.style.display='none';
                    });

                    document.getElementById('container').querySelector( '[ name="'+this.getAttribute('target')+'" ]').parentNode.style.display='block';
                });
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Both of the div displayed even if I did not select anything.. index2.php is above and profile is below to it.

Answer (score 0):

you should try more go and dive into JQUERY or DOM MANU. If you are new you have to start somewhere